# Regex doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having some challenges getting a regex to work correctly.

Basically I need to replace this ":TABLE COUNT #" from a string. # being a number from 0-9.

Here is my code:

```
$("#tbl").each(function() {
  var x = $(this).text();
  var y = x.replace(":TABLE COUNT " + /[0-9]/, "");
  $(this).html(y);
})
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khemikal/9o93831L/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a `regexp` as the first parameter of the `.replace()` method instead a `string`.

[Replace() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

By the way, the `id` attribute should be unique. I replaced `id` attributes by `class`.

```js
$(".tbl").each(function() {
  var x = $(this).text();
  var y = x.replace(/:TABLE COUNT \d/, "");
  $(this).html(y);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="tbl">
  TABLE:TABLE COUNT 3
</p>
<p class="tbl">
  4-WAY
</p>
<p class="tbl">
  TABLE:TABLE COUNT 5
</p>
<p class="tbl">
  TABLE:TABLE COUNT 9
</p>
<p class="tbl">
  4-WAY
</p>
```

`/:TABLE COUNT \d/`means :

Contains this string `:TABLE COUNT` followed by a digit character `\d`

> `\d`: Matches a digit character in the basic Latin alphabet. Equivalent to [0-9].

[RegExp documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

switch from id's to classes, then do something like this:

```
$(".tbl").each(function () {
   var x = $(this).text();
   var y = '":TABLE COUNT " + /[0-9]/, ""';
   $(this).html(y);
});
```

Comment: ID's are faster, literally changing from an ID to a CLASS is not a good answer nor helps me at all

Comment: ok, your each function is going to stop after finding the first element w/ that id

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace